# What is the random number generator in python and numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

```
import random
import numpy.random
```

What is the algorithm for `random` and `numpy.random`. Usually Mersenne Twister is the default generator for matlab, and there are choice to choose which generator to use. What about python, is there a choice for random generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [cpython `random`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/45cce1ea89ea9ec2f155496b783099eec991ef42/Lib/random.py#L30) and [`numpy.random`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1429c606643d1ad305e710c4a31cb6f398d04c53/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L7)  use Mersenne Twister.

Both [cpython `random`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/45cce1ea89ea9ec2f155496b783099eec991ef42/Lib/random.py#L639) and [`numpy.random`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1429c606643d1ad305e710c4a31cb6f398d04c53/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L545) use `/dev/(u)random` on UNIX and `CryptGenRandom` on Windows for entropy.

[Cpython allows to use Wichman Hill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.WichmannHill) as an alternative PRNG, numpy does not (however you can use `random.WichmanHill` to fill a previously allocated array).

Comment: Can we change the generator to others?

Comment: Note that there is work going on to add more random number generators to numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6967