# How to produce random number in a efficient way with c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

I was using boost and QuantLib to produce a 'Array' containing random numbers (standard normal distributed). However, I noticed that the computation performance was not very desirable, and the speed was much slower than simply using numpy of python. Can anyone give me some suggestions?
Many thanks.

Here is my c++ code:

```
using namespace QuantLib;
Array generateRandNumbers(unsigned long seed, Size n) { 
    Array res(n);
    boost::mt19937 rnd(seed); 
    boost::normal_distribution<> normDist(0, 1); 
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::normal_distribution<>> generator_norm(rnd, normDist); 
    BOOST_FOREACH(Real& x, res) x = generator_norm();

    return res;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned long seed = 1; 
    Size n = 1e6;
    boost::timer timer;
    Array randNumbers = generateRandNumbers(seed, n); 
    std::cout << timer.elapsed() << std::endl; 
    return 0
}
```

And this is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import time

ts = time.time()
res = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000000); 
print(time.time() - ts)
```

Comment: Hello to stack overflow (SO). 
We here at SO are eager to help you, but please play along our rules, to make it easier for us. 
Consider reading through the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and 
taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Especially consider reading through 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you compile the C++ code with optimizations turned on?  What were the results of each program?

Comment: Have you turned on compile optimisation (-O3)? You are compiling into release code, right?

Comment: Different pseudo random number generators will work at different speeds and generate different qualities of random numbers. So comparing can be non obvious.

Comment: You are timing initialising the prng as well as generating the samples.

Comment: This question is opinion based (or too broad) - as is asking which library/language is faster.

Comment: @darune no it isn't. It's very specifically asking *why* is *this code* faster than *that code*

Comment: @Caleth in this case we lack the crucial information regarding the compiler, release/debug build type, optimisations flags, specific benchmark results and the hardware.

Comment: @Fureeish Which means it lacks a mcve, not that it's too broad or opinion based

Comment: @Caleth It's just that it is too broad then - we need more information - also what the OP has already tried of experimentation and profiling results, etc.

Comment: We need to know what random number generator python is using too.

Comment: Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868641/what-is-the-random-number-generator-in-python-and-numpy) it is using Mersenne Twister and comparing the constants used in the source code it is the 19937 variant.

Comment: @RoushanSingh the countless questions let me think, why you would try to correct me?? I dont get the the question at hand here and what are the specifics OP is compiling under...

Comment: I see a time of [0.089522 for C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d880628aa2a17ef6) and [0.0632929801941 for python](https://repl.it/repls/OutrageousSugaryPolyhedron)

Comment: In my tests with slightly modified `C++` code (using `std::` not boost) they run about the same speed with `C++` being slightly faster.

Comment: @caleth how can you reconstruct it, if you don't know the specific compiler and settings of the complier??

Comment: @skratchi.at I used online implementations of each language. I'm not implying those are the results that OP saw, but those are *comparable numbers*

Comment: @Caleth i do not want to be mean or something... i just want to point out, that we cant find an answer, without the supported details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You asked:**

> Can anyone give me some suggestions?

The programing language isn't likely to be play a major factor here. Therefore this questions comes down to other parameters:

1. Random number algorithm used (eg. Mersenne Twister)
2. Implementation details of algorithm that may affect perfomance
3. How the code is compiled, linked and run. (release, debugging session, compiler optimizations)

As for the last point - make sure that when making comparison you always use an optimized release build.

Comment: "We all know that c++ is as fast or potential faster than Python can be." citation needed. One of numpy's great strengths is that it is *heavily optimised*

Comment: @Caleth ..and implemented in c/c++ if im not mistaken ?

Comment: My main point is that *languages* are not fast or slow. *language implementations* are. `c/c++` is not a thing. C is a distinctly different language to C++

Comment: @Caleth to me darune is not implying that there are implementations in the language called `C/C++`. He is implying that it's implemented in either of those. I know that "`C/C++`" is a sensitive topic, but don't forget that the `/` *can* also represent logical *or* in sentence construction. But I do fully agree on *implementations* being the key, not the *languages* themselves.

Comment: @Caleth It's just that, a lot of times, many mainstream python libraries are implemented using c/c++ as a goto language because implementing in the language itself (Python) would be too slow- and that the OP seem to imply that somehow the python example is faster.